# Create a view based on XML field

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, view

I have table with a XML field that has specific constant format.How I can create a View based on this field that show me data in this field?

thanks

### EDIT 1)

My Data is like this:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to create a view with all elements in the XML data? How does your data look like? You can create a view with several xPath expressions but that is pretty slow.

Comment: @Albin - do you mean that it is slower to do a xPath query in a view? I would expect the performance to be the same.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson, no, I just say that xPath is quite slow in general. Recently I had to rewrite a view with lots of xPath to concrete tables that I need to maintain, just to get some reasonable performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create something like this

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vEmployees]
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT
    person.n.value('ID[1]', 'int') AS ID,
    person.n.value('Name[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') AS Name,
    person.n.value('LastName[1]', 'navarchar(50)') AS LastName
    FROM dbo.Table x
    CROSS APPLY x.XmlColumn.nodes('/Employees/Person') person(n)

GO
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the same as creating any view.

```
create view vName
as
select somecolumn
from sometable
```

Just insert your query that uses the XML column to get your values instead.

Comment: If I Use XPath is it to slow for 1,000,000 record?

Comment: If something is "slow" or not is something only you can figure out. It depends on a lot of things an much is dependent on the expectations of the user. I can tell you that it is alot faster query your data if you store it in normalized tables instead of as XML.